# Хорошо хоть и... Нужна ли запятая перед "и"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

**Хорошо хоть(,) и** он тоже получил.

**Хорошо хоть(,) и** ему тоже досталось.

Ну, Федя, поганец мелкий, чуть из-за него работу не потерял. Теперь с ним надо держать ухо востро. Хорошо хоть(,) и ему выговор сделали.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Другое решение (ответ изменен):**

***Хорошо хоть,**  и он тоже получил.*

***Хорошо хоть,**  и ему тоже досталось.*

*Ну, Федя, поганец мелкий, чуть из-за него работу не потерял. Теперь с ним надо держать ухо востро. **Хорошо хоть,**  и ему выговор сделали.*

**Пояснение**

Семантика: **Хорошо хотя бы то**, что и  ему досталось.

***Хорошо хоть,** и ему досталось.*

Тогда уступительная часть: **хорошо хоть**. Главная часть: **и ему досталось.**

**ХОТЬ**
ХОТЬ1, сз. (может сопровождаться част. «и», к-рая ставится **перед сказуемым придаточной части**).

1.0. уступит. Употр. **для присоединения придаточной части** сложноподчинённого предложения и указывает на то, что названное в ней обстоятельство является основанием совсем для другого (часто **противоположного)** действия, события, чем то, о к-ром говорится в главной части (**придаточная часть ****может предшествовать** главной, следовать за ней либо находиться в середине её;

Comment: Да, я так же думал. Плюс.